# Initiating spring bean in wicket's AuthenticatedWebSession

Tags: spring, wicket

So I'm trying to initiate spring bean in a class that extends wicket's AuthenticatedWebSession.

There are some answers present in stakcoverflow, but those did not work for me.

```
public class AuthWebSession extends AuthenticatedWebSession {
    @SpringBean(name = "authenticationService")
    private AuthenticationService authenticationService;

    public AuthWebSession(Request request) {
        super(request);
        Injector.get().inject(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean authenticate(String username, String password) {
        //authenticationService is null here as the spring bean did not initiate
        authenticationService.auth(username, password);
    }

    ...
}
```

authenticationService stays null as the spring bean was not initiated. Using wicket version 7.3.0

Any ideas how in inject it correctly?

Comment: Does your xml file contain `<context:component-scan>` with the packages to scan enabled ?

Comment: The bean is found when I include it in `extends Base` class thus the problem should not be with component-scan?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the correct way. The bean should be non-null after `Injector.get().inject(this);` is executed.

I use the same in my current application. Again 7.3.0.

Here are some suggestions:

- Make sure your tests use YourWicketApplication or if they use mock application then make sure to configure SpringComponentInjector.
- Make sure that `@SpringBean` is Wicket-Spring's one, because Spring 5 also added annotation with that name. Although I doubt you use Spring 5 snapshots yet.

Please create a mini demo application that reproduces the issue and we will help debug it!

Comment: Bean should be correct one `import org.apache.wicket.spring.injection.annot.SpringBean;`

Comment: Yep you are right. It should be not null and it is... I was initiating it via unit tests, but when running with jetty it works fine. But the problem still persists as I need it to work with unit tests as well (not mocking).

Comment: Make sure you have SpringComponentInjector set up in your tests. Probably WicketTester uses another Application instance, e.g. MockApplication, instead of the one you use at runtime.

Comment: That must be the problem, I don't have SpringComponentInjector set up in tests... Tried to do it but do not know how, I need to get my hands on getComponentInstantiationListeners somehow.

Comment: See this example: https://github.com/apache/wicket/blob/3001b87000ba670a204504c1bfb07254aabe718d/wicket-spring/src/test/java/org/apache/wicket/spring/injection/annot/SpringBeanTest.java#L53